# How to put borders between elements that are shown and hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this style to put a border in between the elements of a list. The elements are divs.

```
.event-type:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I show and hide these elements in JavaScript. The problem is that when I hide the last element there is a border at the bottom of the list. Is there a way around this using CSS alone?

```
<div class='event-type'>One</div>
<div class='event-type'>Two</div>
<div id='test' class='event-type'>Three</div>

<script>
    $('#test').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Show us your whole code (HTML and JavaScript stuff). It's impossible to see the issue... Make a snippet...

Comment: If you are hiding it (and not removing it from the DOM)... *it's still the last child*.

Comment: how are you hiding it? Please show your javascript that hides the elements.

Comment: I'd use a **top border** that's not on the the `first-child`..might be a quick fix.

Comment: you an use jQuery remove() to remove it from the DOM. If you just hide it, it's still the last-child, here a small example: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/LdLVzE

Comment: @Paulie_D Then you'd have exactly the same issue, only with the first element.

Comment: Yes...i said a quick fix.I don't think it would be an issue unless the first element was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from your CSS that loads before the JS which manipulates the DOM. Try using the reverse logic. Add top borders and remove border for the first item. That way if you any list item the borders reorder themselves and styling remains.

```js
const lc = document.querySelector("#lastid");
lc.style.display = 'none';
```

```css
li {
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List 1i</li>
  <li>List 2i</li>
  <li>List 3i</li>
  <li>List 4i</li>
  <li>List 5i</li>
  <li>List 6i</li>
  <li>List 7i</li>
  <li>List 8i</li>
  <li>List 9i</li>
  <li id="lastid">List 10i</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How do you know what the issue is without seeing OP's markup or JS?

Comment: @TylerH some of the comments in the question gave hints and I tested a couple of situations.

Comment: CSS doesn't care when the DOM is manipulated. (I upvoted, incidentally, it's just the opening sentence that's not right)

Comment: Please share more details @LeeKowalkowski

Comment: I mean you can declare your CSS rules at my time, and traditionally CSS is declared before the HTML body.  So loading CSS before JS can manipulate the DOM is not an issue.